# Optimal sensor placement formulation as multi-armed bandit

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-armed-bandits

Assume that I have $n$ sensors to be placed optimally in $N$ possible locations where $n<<N$.
How can I model this problem as a multi-armed bandit problem?

Comment: Can you describe what a multi-armed bandit problem is? That's the first step to understand how you can formulate this problem. I'd recommend that you read the related chapter in the "Introduction to Reinforcement Learning" book by Sutton and Barto. This also looks like a homework and you should tag it with [tag:homework].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might have a problem with large $n$, but you can consider every possible allocation as an action, and  do that as a multi-armed bandit problem.

For example, say you have 2 sensors and 3 spots, then you have:

- action 1: sensors in spots 1 and 2
- action 2: sensors in spots 1 and 3
- action 3: sensors in spots 2 and 3

then, just run some simulations and figure out the best possible allocation